# Maximum of the periodogram of a truncated sequence

Tags: pr.probability, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence, fourier-transform

Suppose that $Z,Z_1,Z_2,\ldots$ are iid random variables such that $\operatorname EZ=0$, $\operatorname EZ^2=1$ and $\operatorname E|Z|^s<\infty$ with some $s>2$. Let $\tilde Z_t=Z_tI_{\{|Z_t|\le n^{1/s} \}}$ with $1\le t\le n$  be the triangular array of the truncated random variables, where $I_A$ is the indicator function of a set $A$. Denote the periodograms
$$
I_{n,Z}(\lambda)=\Bigl|n^{-1/2}\sum_{t=1}^n\exp(-i\lambda t)Z_t\Bigr|^2
\quad\text{and}\quad
I_{n,\tilde Z}(\lambda)=\Bigl|n^{-1/2}\sum_{t=1}^n\exp(-i\lambda t)\tilde Z_t\Bigr|^2
$$
for $\lambda\in[0,\pi]$.

> I would like to show that
>   \begin{equation}\label{eq1}\tag{#}
> \max_{1\le j\le q}I_{n,Z}(\omega_j)-\max_{1\le j\le q}I_{n,\tilde Z^{(n)}}(\omega_j)\to0
> \end{equation}
>   a.s. as $n\to\infty$, where $\omega_j=2\pi j/n$ with $j=1,\ldots q$ and $q=\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor$. Intuitively speaking, this means that the truncation does not affect the asymptotic behaviour of the maximum of a periodogram.

I am trying to verify a proof of this statement, which is given [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1022677270) (see Lemma 3.3). The proof establishes that
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}\tag{*}
\sum_{t=1}^n|Z_t-\tilde Z_t|=\sum_{t=1}^n|Z_t|I_{\{|Z_t|>n^{1/s}\}}
\end{equation}
converges to $0$ almost surely as $n\to\infty$ and then it is claimed that the periodograms of the sequences $Z_1,\ldots,Z_n$ and $\tilde Z_1,\ldots,\tilde Z_n$ have to be identical identical a.s. for all $n$ sufficiently large. However, I am struggling to see why \eqref{eq2} implies \eqref{eq1}. In my opinion, \eqref{eq2} implies that
$$
\max_{1\le j\le q}\Bigl|n^{-1/2}\sum_{t=1}^n\exp(-i\omega_jt)Z_t-n^{-1/2}\sum_{t=1}^n\exp(-i\omega_jt)\tilde Z_t\Bigr|^2
\le\Bigl|n^{-1/2}\sum_{t=1}^n|Z_t-\tilde Z_t|\Bigr|^2\to0
$$
a.s. as $n\to\infty$ and I do not see a way to conlcude that \eqref{eq1} holds. Maybe I am missing something trivial or maybe I do not understand the proof properly. So does \eqref{eq2} imply that \eqref{eq1} holds?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If (*) converges to 0, that means for a.e. realization of $(Z_t)$, for all sufficiently large $n$, $|Z_t|<n^{1/s}$ for all $t\le n$. That is $Z_t=\tilde Z_t$ for all $t\le n$. Since they are equal for large $n$, they have equal periodograms.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb You're right. I think I dropped the squares in transcribing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A_N$ be the event defined by 
$$
A_N:=\bigcup_{n=2^{N-1}+1}^{2^N}\left\{\max_{1\le j\le q}I_{n,Z}(\omega_j)\neq \max_{1\le j\le q}I_{n,\tilde Z^{(n)}}(\omega_j)\right\}.
$$
Then the following inclusion holds
$$
A_N\subset \bigcup_{n=2^{N-1}+1}^{2^N}\bigcup_{t=1}^n\left\{ Z_t\neq \widetilde{Z_t}^{(n)} \right\}= \bigcup_{n=2^{N-1}+1}^{2^N}\bigcup_{t=1}^n\left\{ \left\lvert Z_t\right\rvert\gt  n^{1/s} \right\}=\bigcup_{t=1}^{2^N}\left\{ \left\lvert Z_t\right\rvert\gt  \left(\max\left\{2^{N-1}+1,t\right\}\right)^{1/s} \right\}.
$$
Using the fact that the random variables $Z_t,1\leqslant t\leqslant n$, have the same distribution, we infer that 
$$
\Pr\left(A_N\right)\leqslant 2^N\Pr\left\{ \left\lvert Z_1\right\rvert\gt  2^{\frac{N-1}s} \right\}
$$
and since $\mathbb E\left\lvert Z\right\rvert^s$ is finite, we derive finiteness of $\sum_{N=1}^{+\infty}\Pr\left(A_N\right)$ and the Borel-Cantelli lemma allows to conclude.

Comment: Thank you very much (+1)! Could you please explain how we derive finiteness of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\operatorname{Pr}(A_n)$? We have that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\operatorname{Pr}(|Z_1|>n^{1/s})\le\operatorname E|Z_1|^s<\infty$. Is it true that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\operatorname{Pr}(|Z_1|>n^{1/s})<\infty$ as well?

Comment: Actually not necessarily hence I had to use dyadics in the revision.